# Aux output (3.5mm) not triggered when inserting headphone

Tags: audio

**tl;dr: Is there a way to check that my phone is aware of the existence of my 3.5 mm aux port?**

I have a [Blackview BV4900 Pro](https://www.gsmarena.com/blackview_bv4900_pro-11570.php) running [Lineage 19-20220613-UNOFFICIAL-arm64_bvS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/andyyan-gsi/files/lineage-19.x/), and nothing happens (= the sound is still played through the speakers) when I insert a headphone cable in the 3.5mm audio jack slot.

I have:

- Checked that the jack slot used to work with the original Rom,
- Tried the headphones on a different device,
- Tried different headphones on the same device,
- Disabled AudioFX,
- Disabled bluetooth,
- Checked the audio settings,
- Restarted the device,
- Checked that the slot was not dirty.

How do I try and understand what is wrong?

I [have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11201711/2657549) `adb shell dumpsys | grep headset` to see if there is anything related to my issue, but could not find anything relevant.

Comment: Did you report to ROM developer? Or search in the ROM discussion forums?

Comment: 1. I have not, the rom is "unofficial" and supports (more or less correctly) a wide range of devices. 2. Yes, with no luck. My question could be better rephrased as "_Is there a way to check that my phone recognize my jack port_"?

Comment: IDK if there is a way now but this [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48803016) says there isn't// download [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.robertlevonyan.testy) and under tests, run the audio test. On my phone it plays music through speakers and through earphones when I plug them in// If it doesn't, it's either a ROM issue or hardware issue, since you indicate that there isn't a problem with the headphones

Comment: Probably obvious, but did it ever work even before flashing LineageOS? P.S. [Andy Yan](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/150986/andy-yan) is one of our users here.

Comment: It did, thanks for checking out.